# Angularjs + Jquery Slideup animatino not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using angularjs and jquery together, and the slide animations are not working, but the fade animations are. Can someone explain to me why that's happening?

Comment: You should show some code.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing some code. Angular and JQuery don't mix very well together as they  tend to "clash" when used to manipulate the DOM.

If you want to do animations with Angular I recommend you look into Angular animations. Some good resources:

- http://slid.es/gsklee/animation-in-angularjs
- http://slid.es/gsklee/animation-in-angularjs-12
- http://www.nganimate.org/